# Как определить событие css

Tags: jquery, события

Доброго времяни суток возникла ситуация что надо определить произошло ли событие это событие проходитв плагине contatn form 7 cms Wordpress  при нажатии полностью заполненой формы код выглядит так 
HTML

```
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ok" style="display: block;"></div>
```

Я пишу следующий код jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 if $('.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok').css('display','block')(function(e) {
  alert(ok);
});
```

понятно что ни чего не происходит почему не подскажите ?

Comment: не вижу здесь события вообще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прилепи это к какому-то событию, например `.blur`